# How to inject a script tag using webpack4

Tags: javascript, webpack-4

I´m trying to insert dynamically a script tag:

```
let div = document.createElement('div')
let scriptTag = document.createElement('script')
scriptTag.type = "text/javascript";
scriptTag.innerHTML = `
function closeModal() {
document.getElementById('contact-edit-modal${contact.id ? '-'+contact.id : ''}').remove()
}
function saveChanges('${createContact}'){
debugger
if ('${createContact}') {
  // creating new contact

  let userData = window.app.getUser()
  if (userData){
    let apiKey = userData.apiKey
    if (apiKey){
      let clientId = userData.clientId
      if (clientId) {
        gapi.client.init({... `

div.append(scriptTag) 
document.body.append(div)
```

and it is in fact injecting the script tag inside the DOM tree

[image]

but the debugger keyword is not making the interpreter stop

[image]

My webpack.config.js is in this link:

https://pastebin.com/x3GqrdWG

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure on this one but I think that debugger statements are parsed **only** at initial load meaning that it's not possible to add debugger statement dynamically.

BTW why are you adding   tag in a div? Why not just append it on window.body?

Comment: hello there, thanks for answering.. anyhow, is there anyway for me to setup a debugging breakpoint to a dynamically appended script code? because in the current context I´m not being able to correctly assert any way to achieve this goal.... thanks in advance...